# Apache spark - what happens if you incorrectly spell properties

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

I am modifying default properties in Apache spark. I spin the clusters using EMR on AWS. However, I am setting properties, and unsure how to check if my new configurations are replacing the default configurations.

As an example, I want to modify the default serialisation in Spark. Hence, I supply the following configuration when creating the cluster.

"Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
        "spark.serializer": "org.apache.spark.serializer:KryoSerializer"

When I then check the spark properties through Spark UK on port :4040 or through YARN method, I see the property there as being set. However, it is unclear if Spark is using this property. Is there a way to check?

I ask this as I once misspelt "spark.serializer" but still saw the property set. I would like to have seen an error thrown showing me that an unknown property is trying to be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already tested if you misspell property name it is accepted but not used. Since a list of possible properties is open and users can set their own properties and error on potentially unused property is not an option.